# Android string resource multi-language

Tags: android, internationalization, android-resources

I have a string that accept a N number of parameters, and i want to internationalise it. Each Locale must have different number of parameters.

Example:

R.string.string_test

1. pt-BR: Tem o parametro %1$s e %2$s;
2. es-AR: Tiene el parámetro  %1$s;
3. en-US: Have param %1$s, %2$s and %3$s;

The problem is that when I use:

```
getString(R.string.string_test, param1, param2);
```

the IDE shows an error, there is a way of doing that? Or I need to create one string each locale?

Answer (score 0):

The IDE showing you an error and the program actually crashing are two different things (in this case). What you are trying to do is fine, as long as the matching-numbered params have the same meaning in each language.

Make sure that you pass enough params to satisfy the string with the most format specifiers. In your example, en-US has three but you're only passing two params to `getString()`.

You can use `@SuppressLint("StringFormatInvalid")` to get the IDE to ignore the warning.

Comment: It doesn't crashe, I'm just curious to see if there is a better way of doing that.